# Декомпозиция библиотек

Tags: .net

Скажем, начали писать либу.

Писали писали, а потом захотелось ее поделить на несколько(переосмысление дизайна), а кодовая база, которая использует исходную либу уже разрослась.

Или переезды классов между пространствами имен...

Есть ли варианты выполнить декомпозицию ничего не поломав, что было ранее создано?

Comment: Что вы боитесь поломать? Имеется в виду ,что нужно сохранить работоспособность приложений, которые используют вашу dll как ссылочную?

Comment: @DmitriyZagorulkin Ну скажем, есть приложение стороннее, которое юзает старую либу. И вот вопрос в том, можно ли хитро подсунуть новую версию, что бы не менять первоначальное приложение.

Comment: @iluxa1810 можно. сохраните тот же публичный интерфейс. внутри - хоть с нуля переписывайте

Comment: @PashaPash разве это поможет при декомпозиции? Были Либа 1, стала Либа 1 и Либа 2. Программа по прежнему будет хотеть взять тип из Либа 1, который теперь в Либа 2. По моему, в .Net какой-то спец. атрибут есть для переездов, но что-то вспомнить его не могу

Comment: TypeForwardedToAttribute

Comment: @PashaPash Хм... похоже на то. А что будет, если исходная сборка будет ссылаться на 2 другие сборки, где одинаковое название типа и использовать TypeForwardedToAttribute ?

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае вам нужно сохранить публичный интерфейс вашей dll. Иначе стороннее приложение просто не найдёт нужный класс, метод, свойство и т.п. Можно пометить изменяемые данные атрибутом Obsolete. В параметре этого атрибута можно указать дополнительную информацию. Внутреннее же устройство dll можете изменить. Конечно же, если стороннее приложение с помощью рефлексии использует непубличные данные, то остаётся риск, что всё равно что-то поломается.